# Is there a word that means both "listen" and "read"?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

I am looking for a word that encapsulates both listen and read.

> I enjoy _______ poetry, rap, etc.

Since poetry and rap can both be read and listened to, I wasn't sure what word to use.

Comment: You don't actually *need* anything in the blank in that particular sentence; you could just say *I enjoy poetry, rap, etc.* and let "enjoy" be the only verb. I'd be interested in a hypernym, though, if there is one, so you could say something like *I ___ a lot of books* and mean both written and audio books.

Comment: Did you look in a thesaurus for both listen and read? There might be good suggestions there. There's also the much more general 'experience' or 'consume' but those sound funny. Also it would work without any word at all "I enjoy poetry, rap, etc".

Comment: I sure hope there is! I've often struggled with this when talking about facility with a language. Similarly with "speak" and "write". So far, I've usually gone with the wordy-sounding "listening to and reading". Please, O collective wisdom of EL&U, I beg thee, give us an answer!

Comment: @1006a 'you don't need...' the best tool for learning is curiosity. Let the OP have what they want;)

Comment: i'd go with "gnoshing".   maybe "snarfing".

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. Indeed! Occasionally a non-answer answer is exactly what you need—but not often. It's like asking someone to show you how to operate jumper cables and they say "You'd be happier living as a hermit in the forest. Then you wouldn't need jumper cables because you wouldn't need to start your car."

Comment: @Abstractioniseverything. I'm certainly not trying to keep the OP from getting what they want—as I said, I'd also be interested in a hypernym. But sometimes we're so caught up in thinking about an issue a certain way that an otherwise-obvious answer eludes us.

Comment: Yes, I agree. I was not insinuating that you were intentionally withholding. I only meant, that while, as you suggested, there is no real need for further elaboration in the given context, it is obvious that the OP is curious. The context provided is not grammatically conducive in terms of usage. However, the context can become more relevant with insight into possibilities.

Comment: I'm not a fan of that example sentence (as I think it's misleading some of the answers). A better sentence would be: "I'm going to ______ poetry and rap tomorrow".

Comment: There should be a badge for 'Ask a question that gets three or more answers with negative votes'.

Comment: @dwjohnston Ha ha. Even funnier because 1006a's comment is the best "answer."

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The word [**browse**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/browse) can be used for both books and music.

As pointed out in comments by 1006a, your example sentence does not even need a word - using Lauren's suggestion instead

> I'm going to **browse** (some) poetry and rap tomorrow

Also imho the word [**peruse**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peruse) should be a good fit as well, you could use *browse* for less intensity while *peruse* is more appropriate for a dedicated session of reading or listening without letting anyone disturb you.

***Some links to sites that show this usage for music***:

Find and Browse Music on Last.fm - https://www.last.fm/music

Music Playlist Channel on Youtube - https://www.youtube.com/user/browsemusicvideos

Browse Music by Artist - https://www.tunefind.com/browse/artist/a

***Some links to sites showing this usage for books***:

Browse Books by Subject - https://www.barnesandnoble.com/h/books/browse

Browse Books & eBooks By Title - http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/browse/books/title/

Comment: I'm unconvinced that a native speaker would use either verb to refer to listening to music. And I don't see anything at your links that supports your answer.

Comment: @Clare Added example links to show usage for both contexts.

Comment: That means to browse the *titles* of music so you can choose which ones to *listen* to.

Answer (score 4):

I agree that *enjoy* works on its own, as does *appreciate*. Both of those choices express a favorable response. Another option would be to *experience* the rap or poetry. This choice is more objective and could be used when the outcome of the experience (approval/disapproval) could go either way.

Answer (score 2):

**consume** fits.

From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consume):

> 3b. to enjoy avidly
>
> 5. to utilize as a customer

We typically think of consuming as in to eat or drink - but it can mean anything that you utilise. People's *[media consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_consumption)* is a fairly common phrase.

For example:

> I enjoy consuming poetry, rap, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with 1006a and Mitch -- enjoy works fine.

Merriam-Webster includes this definition of ***enjoy***:

> ***[enjoy](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enjoy)***
>
> intransitive verb
>
> :  to have a good time
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1. :  to have for one's use, benefit, or lot :  **experience**
>    *enjoyed great success*

(Emphasis mine)

Dictionary.com has these definitions:

> ***[enjoy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/enjoy?s=t)***
>
> verb (used with object)
>
> 1. to experience with joy; take pleasure in:
>    *He enjoys Chinese food.*
> 2. to have and use with satisfaction; have the benefit of:
>    *He enjoys an excellent income from his trust funds.*

So it seems to me that one can enjoy enjoying books and music... or, simply, enjoy them.

> I enjoy poetry, rap, etc.
>
> I enjoy a lot of books

Although for the latter, I would probably add "*and audiobooks*" just to be clear.

Also, I will note that I use "*consume*" with my kids all the time in this sense -- they are supposed to create something before they consume something, meaning that they have to draw a picture or write a story or something like that before they get to watch TV or play a computer game.  (Reading books is an exception to this because I'd have more luck getting them to stop breathing.)  But outside my (admittedly weird) family, it might sound weird to people.

Comment: What if you don't like ____ing the poetry, rap, etc.?

Comment: _I don't enjoy **taking in** / **experiencing** poetry, rap, etc._?

Comment: This is hardly an answer to 'Is there a word that means both “listen” and “read”?' 'Enjoy' is both far broader and far narrower, and as Ben implies, the word satisfying OP's request could fit 'I don't enjoy ...... poetry, rap' and even 'I was ...... poetry and rap all evening, but did not like any of it.'

Comment: I'd love to discover a word that means, more specifically, just _listening_ and _reading_.  Until someone comes up with that, I offered the best I could come up with as a solution to the underlying problem -- identifying the enjoyment of multiple forms of media.

Comment: Look at how Mitch offered such advice.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder

*Appreciate*

can be the answer for your question. That's what I would use. I tried to comment, but due to my low reputation, I can only post an answer.

I'd like to ask, how does the following sentence sound?

> I enjoy appreciating poetry, rap, etc.

Does it changes the tone of what curiousdannii wanted to say in the first place?

Please let me know if it does not.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

TO ATTEND TO
1 : to direct one's attention : see —used with to I'll attend to [=deal with] that myself. 2 : to apply oneself attend to your work. 3 : to apply the mind or pay attention : heed attend to his advice.

Comment: Where are the definitions taken from?